# variable i no me funciona en buble for

Tags: javascript

Este es mi script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var dias=['li.lunes','li.martes','li.miercoles','li.jueves','li.viernes'];
var acciones=['.lunes p','.martes p','.miercoles p','.jueves p','.viernesp'];
for(var i=0;i<=dias.length;i++){
 $(dias[i]).hover(function(){
    alert (acciones[i]);
    $(acciones[i]).addClass('mostrar');},function(){
    $(acciones[i]).removeClass('mostrar');
 });
}
});
</script>
```

****La variable i no funciona en acciones[i], pero cuando le pongo un numero ej. acciones[0], si funciona.
Les agradecería su ayuda****

Comment: has importado los CDN de jQuery? que error de muestra en la consola del navegador?

Comment: Si tengo el CDN y en la consola no muestra ningun error, el alert que tengo ahí me muestra "undefined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu variable `i` no es que no funcione, claro que si funciona, pero para lo que quieres hacer digamos que no es lo mas correcto. Hay algo que se llama clausura y alcance de variable ([closure and scope](https://platzi.com/blog/como-funciona-el-scope-en-javascript/)).

Como modo de pruebas comienza haciendo esto, reemplaza la linea `alert (acciones[i]);` por `alert(i);`. Como veras te mostrara dos alert consecutivos con el valor de `6`. Ahora te preguntaras por que muestra el valor de `6` si el valor que se debe de esperar es el `5`, esto se debe a que en el `for` tienes `i<=dias.length` en lugar de `i<dias.length`, corrigiendo el ***menor igual que*** por ***menor que*** el alert te mostrara el valor de 5. (dos alert consecutivos).

Cuando se termina de recorrer el bucle la variable `i` queda con el valor 5 para todos (cuando leas las clausuras y alcance) entenderas el porque. Ahora que tal si el alert lo hacemos de esta forma `alert (acciones[i-1]);`(suponiendo que ya se corrigio el ***menor igual que*** por ***menor que*** en el for), Genial ya el alert muestra `.viernesp` (te fijas que lo tienes mal escrito, le falta un espacio entre viernes y p).

Bien, pero porque muestra dos veces alert, la razon es que `hover` espera dos parametros asi: `hover( handlerIn, handlerOut )`, si solo le pasas un callback el hover lo tomara como handlerIn y handlerOut. Te dejo la documentacion de [hover](https://api.jquery.com/hover/).

La cuestion ahora es como utilizo la variable `i`, pues no es necesario utilizar la variable `i`, por que en el momento en que se realiza o dispara el evento del `hover` atravez de `this` tenemos acceso al elemento que disparo la accion. Prueba con este codigo:

```
for(var i=0;i<dias.length;i++) {
    $(dias[i]).hover(function() {
        $("p", this).addClass('mostrar');
        // o tambien
        //$(this).find("p").addClass('mostrar');
    }, function() {
        $("p", this).removeClass('mostrar');
        // o tambien
        //$(this).find("p").removeClass('mostrar');
    });
}
```

Con esto es suficiente para que cuando pases el mouse sobre la `p` de la lista agrege la clase `mostrar` y cuando salga el mouse elimine la clase.

Aun asi, no te recomiendo utilizar un for para asignar el evento hover, que tal si en ves de eso te ahorras el for y los array `dias[] y acciones[]` de esta forma:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul li").hover(function() {
        $("p", this).addClass('mostrar');
      // o tambien
      //$(this).find("p").addClass('mostrar');
    },function() {
        $("p", this).removeClass('mostrar');
      // o tambien
      //$(this).find("p").removeClass('mostrar');
    });
});
```

Si nesecitas una lista en especifica solo dale un id(por ejemplo dias) y en el selector haces `$("#dias li").hover(function() { ...`

Para finalizar veo que el evento hover solo lo quieres asignar a los elementos `p` dentro de un elemento `li`, si es asi el codigo quedaria mas simplificado de esta forma:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul li p").hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('mostrar');
    },function() {
        $(this).removeClass('mostrar');
    });
});
```

o suponiendo que le das el id dias a la lista:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#dias li p").hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('mostrar');
    },function() {
        $(this).removeClass('mostrar');
    });
});
```

> Te dejo un ejemplo completo que al pasar el mouse cambiar el color y
>   el cursor del parrafo dentro de la lista:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#dias li p").hover(function() {
     $(this).addClass('mostrar');
    },function() {
     $(this).removeClass('mostrar');
    });
});
```

```css
.mostrar{
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
  <body>
    <ul id="dias">
      <li><p>Lunes</p></li>
      <li><p>Martes</p></li>
      <li><p>Miercoles</p></li>
      <li><p>Jueves</p></li>
      <li><p>Viernes</p></li>
    </ul>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: excelente!, tienes razón. estaba complicandome!, ya funciona. Muchísimas gracias. Saludos...